# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vld.h': No such file or directory

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++

all, i tried to use Visual Leak Detector, and followed the instructions:

Visual C++ 2010: Go to View ->Property Manager, select Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user. Select VC++ Directories and then "Include files" from the tree. Add the include subdirectory from the Visual Leak Detector installation directory. Move it to the bottom of the list. Then select "Library files" from the drop-down menu and add the lib\Win32 subdirectory from the Visual Leak Detector installation directory. Again, move it to the bottom of the list. Repeat for Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user, but select lib\Win64 subdirectory instead.

and include  in one of my source file, and got the error c1083, so whats going on?

this is what i entered:

C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32;$(IncludePath)

for Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user

C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win64;$(IncludePath)

for Microsoft.Cpp.X64.user

[image: Property Manager screen shot]

cheers

daiyue

Comment: Clearly you entered the wrong paths.  You didn't document what you entered.

Comment: i have updated my post that added what i entered in the Property Manager.

Comment: i have uploaded the screen shot

Comment: You still didn't put double quotes around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Include Directories" field, add `C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\include;$(IncludePath)` and in the "Library Directories" field type `C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\lib\Win32`. (or \Win64, like in the instructions you have followed).

Note that this setup will get you through the build phase, if the paths are correct. At run time, your executable must find Visual Leak Detector's dll(s) so you could either prepend the `C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\bin` (or the name of the subdirectory containing the binary files - dll and exe) to the "Executable directories" field, or add the `C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\bin` directory to the PATH environment variable, this way your executable will start by simply launching it from Explorer (not only from Visual Studio).

As a third option, you could copy the DLLs from VLD in the same directory as your executable.

Comment: actually, i put C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\include;$(IncludePath) into "Include Directories", and the program compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Put double quotes around paths that contain an embedded space.  And watch out for the difference between `c:\program files` and `c:\program files (x86)` on a 64 bit operating system.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you haven't specified the include path, that is "C:\Program Files\Visual Leak Detector\include" or similar. And I'm not sure about appending $(IncludePath) to the library paths.

> Visual C++ 2010: Go to View ->Property Manager, select Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user. Select VC++ Directories and then "Include files" from the tree. Add the include subdirectory from the Visual Leak Detector installation directory.

The idea is that you must instruct the ide where to look for the files you reference in your project (.lib and .h/.hpp/.hxx/etc). If this doesn't work, please provide more details about each field you entered or maybe some screenshots.

Comment: the appending $(IncludePath) are automatically added by the property manager.